Progress Bar With Server Actions
I am making a multiple file upload for learning. The main logic is done so far but in the front end I want to make some user feedback and trying to make a progress bar. In client-side I've made simulating with random filling progress bar but I want a real progress bar. I don't know how to send tracked upload progress data to the actions. How can I do it?
I've made this with api route but now I am trying to make it with server actions. I tried to use fetch API for sending tracked upload progress data to the actions but couldn't make this properly.

I have the same question. It would be nice to have this feature covered in some way.
